# Difference between thermodynamic terms heat and enthalphy

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, enthalpy

What is the difference between heat and enthalphy?

Comment: What’s the difference between apples and grapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat is defined as the energy that flow into or out of a system because of difference in temperature between the system and its surrounding. Give special attention to the word 'flow'. It is not the energy that is stored in the body in the form of temperature. It is the energy that is transferred due to temperature difference.

Now, Enthalpy is the energy stored in the body at constant pressure. And here the energy is stored.

Comment: To elaborate on this, H is determined exclusively by the thermodynamic state of the system at a certain temperature and pressure (i.e., it is a physical property of the system), while the heat that flows into the system between state A and state B is determined by the process path.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thanks, I forgot about it while answering.